# Cannot cast a ToolStripItem to MenuItem

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I am trying to get the clicked item on a context menu. I derive the following code from what I find on the web, but I am a bit confused with `ToolStripMenu`, `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem`. From what I can find this seems to be the correct way to get the selected menu item but it doesn’t seem to work for me.

I create a context menu when right-clicking on a `DataGrid` row.

In the clicked event I cast the sender to a `MenuItem`. In the debugger the sender looks fine with the two Items but `var mi = sender as MenuItem` just returns null. What am I doing wrong please?

```
ContextMenuStrip my_menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

int position_xy_mouse_row = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
if (position_xy_mouse_row >= 0
{
   DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[position_xy_mouse_row];
   dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[position_xy_mouse_row].Cells[0];

   my_menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem
   {
      Name = "Delete",
      Text = "Delete",
      Tag = "Delete"
    });
    my_menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem
    {
      Name = "Update",
      Text = "Update",
      Tag = "Update"
    });

    my_menu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    my_menu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(my_menu_ItemClicked);
}


private void my_menu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var mi = sender as MenuItem;
    string menuText = mi.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` in this case is the `ContextMenuStrip` which can't be casted to a MenuItem.

What you want is your actual clicked item which is in the `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs`

so with:

```
string menuText = e.ClickedItem.Text;
```

you will receive the Text from the clicked `ToolStripItem`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things. The "Strip" family (`ContextMenuStrip`, `ToolStripItem`, `ToolStripMenuItem`...) replaces the old `ContextMenu`/`MenuItem`... stuff (still present for backward compatibility)

Here the cast fail because it isn't a `MenuItem` and neither a `ToolStripMenuItem` but the source of the event : the `ContextMenuStrip`.

If what you want is the text of the actual clicked item you should use the `ClickedItem` property of the event arguments `e` here ; as stated in Mark's answer too.
*Note `ClickedItem` returns a `ToolStripItem` (which ToolStripMenuItem inherits from)*

Comment: Thank you so very much Mark and Sehnsucht! It is much clearer now.